# Why does defined(X) not work in a preprocessor definition without a space?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

A preprocessor definition that includes `defined(X)` will never evaluate to true, but `(defined X)` will. This occurs in MSVC9; I have not tested other preprocessors. A simple example:

```
#define FEATURE0 1
#define FEATURE1 0
#define FEATURE2 1

#define FEATURE3 (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined(FEATURE2)))
#define FEATURE4 (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined FEATURE2))
#define FEATURE5 (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined (FEATURE2)))

#if FEATURE3
#pragma message("FEATURE3 Enabled")
#elif (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined(FEATURE2)))
#pragma message("FEATURE3 Enabled (Fallback)")
#endif

#if FEATURE4
#pragma message("FEATURE4 Enabled")
#elif (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined FEATURE2))
#pragma message("FEATURE4 Enabled (Fallback)")
#endif

#if FEATURE5
#pragma message("FEATURE5 Enabled")
#elif (FEATURE0 && !FEATURE1 && (defined (FEATURE2)))
#pragma message("FEATURE5 Enabled (Fallback)")
#endif
```

The output from the compiler is:

1>FEATURE3 Enabled (Fallback)
1>FEATURE4 Enabled
1>FEATURE5 Enabled

Working cases: `defined (X)`, `defined( X )`, and `defined X`.
Broken case: `defined(X)`

Why is `defined` evaluated differently when part of a definition, as in the `#if` cases in the example, compared to direct evaluation, as in the `#elif` cases in the example?

Comment: I'm surprised that `defined(foo)` works at all. It's not a function call. The () is as a grouping operator in this case. Grouping `foo` all by itself and away from `defined` makes no sense.

Comment: @John: It is an explicitly allowed form in 16.1/1 and will (on compliant implementations) work every where `defined foo` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defined` is specific to `#if` and `#elif`. When using it through macro expansion the behavior is undefined.

Comment: This is the right answer and explicitly specified by 16.1/4 in the C++03 standard.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `defined(X)` isn't interpreted like a function call (a la `sizeof(X)`), it's parsed by a special language parser.  This parser recognizes `defined` as a modifier to an `if` statement, not as an independent entity.  When you are using `defined(FEATURE2)`, it is not treating `defined` as a keyword but instead as a regular object or `#define`d entity (which doesn't exist in this case, causing your error).  Later, when you use it inside the `elif` statement, the parser treats it as a proper keyword.

To be honest, I wasn't aware that `defined(SOMETHING)` would work in any case.

Answer (score 1):

According to 6.10.1.3 in the C99 spec, the keyword **defined** is only recognized if it appears directly in the expression of the #if before any macro expansion in that expression.  If macro expansion results in the keyword **defined**, the results are undefined.